# Android method NetworkInterface.isUp() not found

Tags: android, api

I have a problem with the android API: if I look at the android API documentation, the method isUP() of the class NetworkInterface exists, but when I try to use it in a code, I can not compile my application. By looking in the android referenced library, I realized that this method is not present in the class.

I precise that I work with Android 2.2 and eclipse Helios.
This is my code:

---

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class startEssai extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
   NetworkInterface n = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().nextElement();
   n.isUp();
  } catch (SocketException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }
}
```

---

Can somebody help me? Maybe the referenced library is the wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Sandrine Beauche.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at right margin of the [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isUp%28%29) name in the Javadoc, it says "Since API level 9" meaning the method was not added until Android 2.3.

```
public boolean isUp ()                                         Since API Level 9
```

You can click through on the *[API Level 9](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level9)* text in the JavaDoc to see a table mapping of API Levels to Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isUp%28%29) states that this method was added in API level 9, which is Android 2.3.  You are developing for Android 2.2, so this method will not be available.